# Dynamic cast for opencv cv::Ptr

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers, casting, dynamic-cast

I am currently implementing different opencv machine learning tools in c++ in the same class. Therefore I have the problem of downcasting pointers of the superclass `cv::ml::StatModel` to the subclass `cv::ml::SVM` (for example).

In online tutorials one usually finds the implementation of opencv classifiers like this:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM> classifier = cv::ml::SVM::create();
```

What I want to do is a dynamic cast in the class constructor. This is part of my class variables:

```
class Classifier{
private:
    cv::Ptr<cv::ml::StatModel> classifier;
    cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM> SVM;
//... followed by more code };
```

And in my constructor:

```
Classifier::Classifier(const char* filename, cv::ml::SVM& svm){
    bool load = Classifier::getData(filename);
    if (load==0){
        cout << "Error opening file!" << endl;
    }
    else{
        classifier = &svm;
        //Here I want to do something linke this, just with cv::Ptr:
        //the following line gives compiler errors because c++ does not know that cv::Ptr is a pointer...
        SVM = dynamic_cast<cv::ml::SVM*>(classifier); 
        Classifier::setUpSVM();
    }
}
```

**Does anyone know if opencv provides an alternative to `dynamic_cast<T>()` for `cv::Ptr` ?** Or alternatively has experience with not using the opencv pointers, but instead "normal" c++ pointers to use the machine learning API? I am wondering if I will run into problems with this implementation, because common practice seems to be using the opencv `cv::Ptr` class.

Comment: As an update to my question: At runtime I get a `Segmentation Fault` error at the `dynamic_cast` line (using normal pointers instead of opencv Ptr). Can anyone help me to do the dynamic cast with the opencv Ptr?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is an openCV alternative of `dynamic_cast<T>()` written specifically for `cv::Ptr`. It's called... [dynamicCast()](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d0/de7/structcv_1_1Ptr.html#a141f3b16ca0fa11727d8daee52b6402e) :D There are also analogical alternatives to const cast and static cast for that matter.

Comment: Aaaah, oh man, sometimes looking thoroughly helps:P I did look in the documentation, but only foud the staticCast:/ Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help ;) Take care!